# Async method that consumes self causes error "returns a value referencing data owned by the current function"

Tags: asynchronous, rust, async-await, reference, builder

Is it possible to consume self in an async method?

Here is my method (please note the `poller` is unrelated to the `poll` method in rust futures).

```rust
pub async fn all(self) -> WebDriverResult<Vec<WebElement<'a>>> {
    let elements = self.poller.run(&self.selectors).await?;
    Ok(elements)
}
```

and for completeness, here is the struct it belongs to:

```rust
pub struct ElementQuery<'a> {
    session: &'a WebDriverSession,
    poller: ElementPoller,
    selectors: Vec<ElementSelector<'a>>,
}
```

NOTE: session is passed in via the new() fn. It is owned by the caller that creates ElementQuery and runs it to completion. The above method should return `Vec<WebElement>`.

The error says:

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local data `self.poller`
   --> src/query.rs:193:9
    |
193 |         self.poller.run(&self.selectors).await
    |         -----------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    |         |
    |         returns a value referencing data owned by the current function
    |         `self.poller` is borrowed here
```

However, as far as I can tell, I am not returning any references owned by the current function. The only reference being returned (inside WebElement) is `session`, which I passed into the struct to begin with.

I can change the ? to unwrap() so that the only return path is `Ok(elements)` just to eliminate any other possibilities (same error).

Here is WebElement:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Clone)]
pub struct WebElement<'a> {
    pub element_id: ElementId,
    pub session: &'a WebDriverSession,
}
```

`ElementId` is just a newtype wrapper around `String` - no references.

Is this something to do with the method returning a `Future` that may execute later? and perhaps something to do with something being held over an `.await` boundary?

If the ONLY reference being returned is `&WebDriverSession`, and that same reference was passed in via `new()`, then why is it telling me that I'm returning a reference owned by the function?

EDIT: Managed to get this to compile by effectively inlining some code rather than calling additional async functions. Still not sure why this fails, other than it seems to be related to holding a reference across .await boundaries, even if that reference is not owned by the function/struct on either side.

Here's a playground link with a simplified example:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f38546480aaeb3594c8c17fec9b7d62c

Comment: Could you create a minimal example that runs in the playground and shows this? It would help with experimenting.

Comment: I'll give it a go

Comment: Here's the same error in a different place but I believe it's the same cause: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=eeb08a60eaef7b3bc88c32552db507fe

Comment: Updated to show an example of it working vs not working depending on whether it calls another async fn vs do the same code inline:
https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=aa1b31319e7cf6988f61c83e23e07cc4

Comment: Your final link has different issues, it borrows selectors (due to `for ... in selectors.iter()`) instead of consuming it (`for ... in selectors.into_iter()` or just `for ... in selectors`). Fixing that reveals an issue with lifetimes, where `run()` ties its result to the lifetime of the selector instead of to the lifetime of the session. [Fixing that](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=78842634064342bad9f522e7f1d5745b) leads to a borrow checker error that I don't quite understand, and which happens regardless of whether `elems` is returned.

Comment: In my actual code that the example is based on, the selectors need to be run repeatedly in a loop (if the first round returns nothing, it waits and tries again, up to a timeout), which means I cannot consume them. Unless I could push them to another Vec afterwards?

Either way thanks for the help thus far. I think I may need to change something in my approach or try some other simple examples to get a better understanding of rust async and borrowing across await boundaries. Another thing I may try is to code this up in synchronous form to make sure the idea is sound.